# schedule post on facebook page using facebooksdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-page

I have written following code to post on facebook page but getting this error message: “(#200) Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself.“;

```
NSString *accesstoken = @"EAACEdEose0cBAAe49xNZBS5MqswXkRptXgLDRuZBZBPZCZCVl5rxW6Bt0jthaHXMACNTiUWePg9XkVTpttDNsLyWYBaEkQaUCm5vbSJQh8zGwkegAcQRjRggAJajunmMyg0jVIKZAZBzMjbZCKWUv1Tie1UzF8gJCpIxACIVgqx7SqKdPZBnIUaElk3meB7SYo6AZD";
NSString *pageId = [dic valueForKey:@"id"];
NSDictionary *dicPara=@{@"message": @"Hello",@"access_token":accesstoken,@"scheduled_publish_time": [NSNumber numberWithInt:timestamp],@"published": @"false"};
NSLog(@"%@",dicPara);

  FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                              initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",pageId]
                                              parameters:dicPara
                                              HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                    // Insert your code here

          if (error)
          {
               NSLog(@"%@",error);
          }
          else
          {
               [arrPostId addObject:[result valueForKey:@"id"]];
          }
     }];
```

Now I have searched for this error and found that you have to set accesstoken of the page instead of user's token. So how can I change user's access token to page accesstoken?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKGraphRequest/

Comment: @CBroe : Using graphapi i am able to successfully schedule post. But from app i'm getting the error i mentioned above.

Comment: How to pass the access token is explained on that page.